# Jumble data in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which holds PII(personally identifiable information) data like email, password. I want to load this data in lower environment by jumbling.

I saw few SQL functions which scrambles data but I dont want to scramble data I want to jumble(shuffle) data.

```
Before jumbling
email             password
abc@gmail.com     pass$123#

Aftter jumbling
email             password
cba@lagmi.mco     1a2#s3ps$
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this and what does it accomplish?

Comment: @Sam this is usually done based on sensitivity of information. People that work with low environments doesn't need to know or even can't know what the real information is. There are countries with even specific laws about this.

Comment: You have to write a script that will go through the specific tables and fields and do your jumbling that's how you do it specifically for what you need.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I understand that people would do this due to PII sensitivity, but my question is more like "Why would you want to do this since it doesn't seem like a secure method to store your data?" There's many better ways to store a password: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17421/how-to-store-salt

Comment: @Sam we are migrating this data to a new system, for migration we developed a new tool. We want to make sure the tool or new system is not rejecting any special characters in these columns.

Comment: @Avi How frequently do you need to "Jumble" this PHI data? only once, or in q predetermined schedule (like monthly, weekly, etc.)? Take a look at this website http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/deid/ This site has helped when we had to deidentify our datasets.

Comment: @Sam Now your question was a lot better explained ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use **fake data** instead of writing code to scramble real data with PII:

https://mockaroo.com/

[image]